# Is this the correct number of permutations?

Tags: combinatorics

How many permutations of the English alphabet do NOT have all five vowels appearing consecutively?

What I have:

Since there are $26$ letters in the alphabet and each letter can be used only once, there are $26!$ arrangements of the letters in the alphabet in a string. There are $21$ arrangements of the vowels surrounded by the consonants:

## 1){string of $5$ vowels}{string of $21$ consonants}

## 2) {string of $1$ consonant}{string of $5$ vowels}{string of $20$ consonants}

...

## 21){string of $21$ consonants}{string of $5$ vowels}

So there are $22(5!)(21!)$ strings of the alphabet in which all $5$ vowels appear consecutively. So there are $26!-22(5!)(21!)$ strings in which the $5$ vowels do not appear consecutively.

(not sure why part of this is showing up in bold font)

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me.

Comment: This seems correct to me, although you probably meant to say that there are $22$ arrangements of "all vowels together" surrounded by consonants (instead of $21$).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

Another way to think of the invalid permutations is to think of the vowels as a single block.  Leaving 22 arrangeable elements.  $22!$ ways to arrange them.  Then, for each arrangement, the vowels can be arranged $5!$ ways.

Giving you $22!5!$ like what you calculated.